# Blank Multiple Choice Item Responses

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to create a response to a Google Form using the updated API. Below is my code:

```
function submitResponse() {
var form = FormApp.openByUrl('some url');
var items = form.getItems();

var itemResponse = items[0].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse('No');
var formResponse = form.createResponse().withItemResponse(itemResponse);
formResponse.submit();    
return;
}
```

The form contains a Yes/No question. Yes and No are the only options and there is only one question. The script runs but it submits a FormResponse containing a blank response to the item. Any ideas?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

I just built a quick copy and this worked for me. The only thing I changed was the typo you have in `itemResponse`.

from:

```
var formResponse = form.createResponse.withItemResponse(itemREsponse);
```

to:

```
var formResponse = form.createResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm crap. I re tested a few times but everytime it seems to fill in blank I don't get it. The summary page for the form says "No responses yet for this question" where it would normally show the graph.

Comment: There may possibly be an issue don't know if this is related yet. 
[link](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=itemResponse&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=2849)